# Асинхронный ввод, вывод MySQL (libmysq)

Tags: mysql

Есть MySQL Cи-АПИ, клиент MySQL позволяет использовать неблокируемые операции в/в
а как это сделать на практике?

Comment: вы видимо не совсем понимаете о чём говорите, всё упирается в типы таблиц, а не API

-----------

например MyISAM на время записи блокирует всю таблицу, и тут как не крути многопоточности не выйдет

Comment: я имею ввиду  выполнение двух разных запросов одновременно, и от вида стороджа, будь то Memory, MyISAM, InnoDb, extrDb или MariaDb не зависит

как это сделать на практике используя асинхронный ввод/вывод?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решение**: [Async MySQL Queries with C-API](http://jan.kneschke.de/2008/9/9/async-mysql-queries-with-c-api/)

Свой вариант c libev в скором выложу на github и напишу статью в блог.